# Runing macro over all columns in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro, lets call it %encoding(dataset, var), which encodes some categorical variable (var) in given dataset.

What I want to do, is to run this macro for all character variables in my dataset, but I don't have idea how to do it. My set has a lot of variables, so writing it manually is out of question.

Comment: Might not even need a macro! Add some sample data with 3 three columns to be encoded, and show how they are to be encoded.  You might need to only apply a **custom format**, or use an **array** to loop over a list of variables that will be processed.  Otherwise, you can use SQL **dictionary.columns** to create a list of variables the macro will process repeatedly via a macro **%DO** loop.

Comment: Can't answer without an example of what's in the macro. It could be that an array makes a ton more sense than macros or that using a user defined format is even faster as well. Macros are likely not the most efficient answer though entirely doable. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you need to physically change all of the character variables in this dataset. You can easily do this in a `data step` loop. The special keyword `_CHARACTER_` selects all character variables for you. Save them into an array and you can loop through them all.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array charvars[*] _CHARACTER_;
     
    do i = 1 to dim(charvars);
        charvars[i] = <logic goes here>;
    end;

   drop i;
run;
```

If you need to do something like change multiple variables' formats, `proc datasets` would be an efficient way to do so. You can use the same trick.

```
proc datasets lib=libref nolist;
    modify have;
        format _CHARACTER_ <format here>;
quit;
```

This macro below changes a specified list of space-delimited variables to a single format you specify, but you can easily modify this to associate specific formats with specific variables in a macro loop.

```
%macro encoding(data=, vars=, format=);

    %let data = %upcase(&data.);

    /* Split out libname and dataset name */
    %if(%scan(&data., 2, .) =) %then %do;
        %let lib = WORK;
        %let dsn = &data.;
    %end;
        %else %do;
            %let lib = %scan(&data., 1, .);
            %let dsn = %scan(&data., 2, .);
        %end;

    proc datasets lib=&lib. nolist;
        modify &dsn.;
            format &vars. &format.;
    quit;

%mend;
```

Example:

```
data cars;
    set sashelp.cars;
run;

%encoding(data=cars, vars=EngineSize Cylinders Horsepower, format=z5.);
```